# Display current on resistor: unknown tikz/i key

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to display a current arrow next to the resistor. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[polish,polish,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{3cm}{3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (2, 2) to[resistor,i=$i$] (2, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

According to the circuitikz documentation, it's how it should be done. However, I get an error message `Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/i', to which you passed '$i$', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Why am I getting this message? What to do to make the file compile?

Comment: Works for me --- what versions of CircuiTikZ etc. are you using?

Comment: According to the `.log` file it's 1.2.5

Comment: Would you mind posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Okay, I've added my whole preamble

Comment: It seems to be that `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}` is causing the problem as it works fine without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using together `circuitikz` and `circuits.ee.IEC`. That is not going to work well... In the manual:

[image]

You can make your example work by:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compatibility]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
     \draw (2, 2) to[*resistor,i=$i$] (2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the compatibility is a *best effort* thing, and very far to be 100% working nor really tested. I would say: decide on one of the two libraries and stick with it...

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new to LaTeX and I didn't realize that tikz's `circuit.ee.IEC` is different library than `circuitikz`

Comment: @MarcinSzwarc - The main difference is that all TikZ shapes get larger if you put text inside them, while circuitikz shapes do not.